# Python Memory Error

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить такую ошибку в `Jupyter Notebook`:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 105. GiB for an array with shape > (14121472334,) and data type int64?

Тип данных поменял на `int32`, все равно не проходит

Comment: Вы попросили 14 миллиардов целых чисел. Это 105Gb памяти. Видимо в вашем компьютере недостаточно  памяти. Подумайте зачем вам нужно 14 миллиардов элементов.

Comment: Обычно, в таких случаях используют батчи - разбивают датасет на куски и обрабатывают каждый отдельно, чтобы каждый из кусков влезал в память.

Comment: Расскажите больше о задаче, приведите ваш код и данные (хотя бы пример данных). Так вот ничего не зная о данных и коде сложно советовать, как уменьшить потребление памяти в 10 раз, или сколько у вас там памяти вообще есть. Методы есть - точное указание типа данных (где-то достаточно и `int8`, разреженные матрицы/массивы, сэмплирование), но нужно знать данные и задачу.